# Creating a custom stream from a class object that has a method that fetches values one by one

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class object that's like a database cursor, it has a `next()` method that reads the next table row.

```
class MyClass{
   Row next() throws DatabaseException {
   ...
   }
}
```

I want to convert this to a stream since this also behaves like a lazy operation.

I tried using Supplier which is accepted by `Stream.generate()`. `Supplier` has a method `get()` which has to be overridden for custom implementations.

```
Stream<Row> stream = Stream.generate (new Supplier <Row>() { 
   @Override public Row get() { 
      // custom implementation
      ...
   }
});
```

The only problem using this is that MyClass.next() throws an exception while Supplier.get() doesnt allow exceptions. Is there any other way to create a custom stream for such class?

Comment: You can rewrite the entire stream API and include the `<T> void foo() throws T` trick, but that's.. rather hacky and not a good idea. You can make your own `UncheckedDatabaseException` and throw that (`try { return x.next(); } catch (DatabaseException e) { throw new UncheckedDatabaseException(e); }`). But, really, lambdas / stream API is not at all a good fit here. "I want to convert this to a stream since this also behaves like a lazy operation" - no you don't. Streams have about 20 properties. This concept shares 'lazy' as one, and misses on the other 19.

Answer (score 1):

First, note the types in `java.util.function` and `java.util.stream` do not support throwing *checked* exceptions. If you really want to stream your rows, then somewhere you're going to have to catch the checked exception, wrap it in an *unchecked exception*, and then throw said unchecked exception. In the attempt you show in your question, you would do that inside the `Supplier` implementation.

That said, the `generate` method creates an *infinite* stream. I doubt you have an infinite number of rows to return. The next method to consider is `iterate` (the finite overload), but the arguments it takes don't lend themselves to what you're trying to do. At least not directly.

Probably the most correct solution is to first create a [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Spliterator.html) implementation to iterate the rows. Then use [`StreamSupport`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html) to create a `Stream`.

For example:

```java
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class MyClassSpliterator extends AbstractSpliterator<Row> {

    public static Stream<Row> streamRows(MyClass myClass) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(new MyClassSpliterator(myClass), false);
    }

    private final MyClass myClass;

    public MyClassSpliterator(MyClass myClass) {
        // Assumes an unknown number of rows. Also, assumes NONNULL
        // characteristic due to the assumption that a null value
        // means there's no more rows to process. Add or change
        // characteristics as appropriate.
        super(Long.MAX_VALUE, NONNULL);
        this.myClass = Objects.requireNonNull(myClass);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super Row> action) {
        try {
            // Assumes MyClass#next() will return null when there's no
            // more rows to process.
            Row next = myClass.next();
            if (next != null) {
                action.accept(next);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } catch (DatabaseException ex) {
            // Should probably create and use a custom unchecked exception
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Where you place the `Spliterator` implementation and the `streamRows` method are obviously up to you.

Note the above extends [`AbstractSpliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator.html). That class makes it easier to create `Spliterator` implementations. By default, it supports limited and relatively naive parallelism. It basically just buffers a bunch of elements so they can be split up. If you have a better splitting solution, or just don't want to support any splitting, then override the `trySplit()` method.

And note if you already have an `Iterator` implementation for your `MyClass`, then it may be more appropriate to use one of the methods in [`Spliterators`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Spliterators.html) to create the `Spliterator`.

Comment: Regardless of whether you have a way to support more efficient splitting, you need only half the code by implementing `Spliterator` directly, as you only have to implement *one* method with a logic straight-forwardly matching the logic of `myClass.next()`. It’s also more efficient than converting the single-method logic to the `hasNext()/next()` logic, just to have it converted back to single-method logic in `spliteratorUnknownSize`.

Comment: Yes, but I was not really considering the number of methods you have to implement. I'm of the opinion that `Iterator` is simply easier to understand conceptually, even if the implementation gets split up between two methods. It has only one basic concern.

Comment: I disagree. The very method you are wrapping, follows the principle of having one method providing the next value or telling that there is none. That’s a very natural concept, see `BufferedReader.readLine()`, for example. Splitting the logic into two methods only feels natural, because you are used to it. Because that’s how the much older `Iterator` interface works.